# How to partition $S$ in this way?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Assume: 
$$
P =\{p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_K\}\subset \{1,2,\dots,N\},\quad |P| = K, \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}_+^K , \qquad w = e^{-j\frac{2\pi}N}
$$
and,
$$
f(l) = \sum_{i=1}^K \sum_{j=1}^K x_i x_j w^{(p_i-p_j)l}
$$
I am going to find $x$ and $P$ such that these equalities are satisfied:
$$
f(1) = f(2) = \cdots = f(N-1)
$$
We can change this problem to an easier problem by defining : 
$$
S_d = \{(i,j) \quad | \quad p_i - p_j \mod N = d\}, \qquad d=0,1,\cdots,N-1
$$

So :

$$
f(l) = \sum_{d=0}^{N-1} \underbrace{\sum_{(i,j) \in S_d} x_i x_j}_{g[d]} \space w^{ld}
$$

Now suppose :
$$
S =S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \cdots \cup S_{N-1} =  \{(i,j), \quad 1\leq i,j \leq K, \quad i \ne j \}
$$

Using properties of Discrete Fourier Transform it can be shown that this problem turns to the problem :

> $$
> g[d] = \sum_{(i,j) \in S_d} x_i x_j = \frac1{N-1} \sum_{(i,j) \in S} x_i x_j\quad, \qquad d=1,2,\cdots,N-1
> $$

i.e. the problem becomes finding partition(s) of $S$ and $\{x_i\}_{k=1}^K$ (up to a scale!) satisfying the above equalities.

If for simplicity we set the values $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_K = 1$, the problem will reduce to this:

$$
|S_d|=\frac{K(K-1)}{N-1}, \quad d=1,2,\cdots,N-1
$$
so, for the case of $\frac{K(K-1)}{N-1}$ being integer, the solution for $x$ and cardinality of partitions is found. Any idea for the case it is not integer?
**Even finding cardinality of partitions would be great!**

Any contribution would be appreciated.

**Edit: Through simulations I reached the result that the solution of this problem for $|S_d|$ is $\{|S_d|\}_{d=1}^{N-1}$ with minimum variance under constraint of $\sum_{d=1}^{N-1}|S_d| = K(K-1)$ which leads to some of them being $\lfloor \frac{K(K-1)}{N-1}\rfloor$ and the others $\lfloor \frac{K(K-1)}{N-1}\rfloor+1$.**

Since the question has not received enough attention I asked it in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137705/is-such-a-partition-possible) too

Comment: What is $p_i$ is it an element of vector $P$? If so, how is the vector $P$ defined, the notation is a little unclear to me at least.... is it an increasing list of integers from $1..N$?

Comment: @GrahamHesketh Actually $P$ is a set and $P = \{p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_K\} \subset \{1,2,\cdots,N\}$

Comment: So to solve your problem you are allowed to create a vector $P$ that draws $K$ arbitrary integers from the set of integers between $1$ and $N$ right?

Comment: @GrahamHesketh Yes, but since $P$ is a set, $p_i$'s are distinct. As I stated, we are looking for $P$ and $x$ satisfying those equalities